# How to work with coordinates in Matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to make visible the impact of balance sheet symmetric changes on the level of activities. In particular, given that (in general) the level of activities are concave functions of balance sheets, I want to highlight the asymmetric changes in the level of activities arising from a symmetric change in balance sheets.

So far, I've been able to make all of the dynamics fairly explicit. I just want to add a final detail: the trajectories of the change on the 'level of activity' function. The problem is that I am not able to make python use the x-coordinates I would like it to use.
Graphically, the problem is just one of shifting the 'phase diagram' lines to the right (even though simply subtracting some numbers from the square root does not help).

Here is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


# Create Figure and Axes instances
fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 6))

BS = np.linspace(1,9,9)
LoA = np.sqrt(BS)
plt.plot(LoA)

## initial situation: 
## firm A has a better balance sheet position than B

# Firm A
plt.plot([5,5],[1,6**(1/2)],'g',marker='o',ls=':')
plt.plot([0,5],[6**(1/2),6**(1/2)],'g',marker='o',ls=':')

# Firm B
plt.plot([3,3],[1,4**(1/2)],'m',marker='o',ls=':')
plt.plot([0,3],[4**(1/2),4**(1/2)],'m',marker='o',ls=':')


## final situation
## frim A gains symmetrically vis-à-vis firm B

# Firm A
plt.plot([7,7],[1,8**(1/2)],'g',marker='o',ls=':')
plt.plot([0,7],[8**(1/2),8**(1/2)],'g',marker='o',ls=':')

# Firm B
plt.plot([1,1],[1,2**(1/2)],'m',marker='o',ls=':')
plt.plot([0,1],[2**(1/2),2**(1/2)],'m',marker='o',ls=':')

## Graph design

plt.annotate('Firm A\'s gain', xy=(0, 2.639), xytext=(3, 2.60), xycoords='data', 
            fontsize=7*1.5, ha='center', va='bottom',
            bbox=dict(boxstyle='square', fc='white'),
            arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle='-[, widthB=2.1, lengthB=.7', lw=1.5))

plt.arrow(5,1,1.8,0, head_width=0.05, head_length=0.1, fc='g', ec='g')

plt.annotate('Firm B\'s loss', xy=(0, 1.7), xytext=(0.87, 1.663), xycoords='data', 
            fontsize=7*1.5, ha='center', va='bottom',
            bbox=dict(boxstyle='square', fc='white'),
            arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle='-[, widthB=3.5, lengthB=.7', lw=1.5))

plt.arrow(3,1,-1.8,0, head_width=0.05, head_length=0.1, fc='m', ec='m')


XA = [6,7,8]
YA = np.sqrt(XA)
plt.plot(YA,'g',marker = '>')

XB = np.arange(2,5)
YB = np.sqrt(XB)
plt.plot(YB,'m',marker = '<')


plt.xlabel("Balance Sheet")
plt.ylabel("Level of Activity")
plt.title("Asymmetric Balance Sheet Effect on Level of Activity")
# Turn off tick labels
#ax.set_yticklabels([])
#ax.set_xticklabels([])
plt.show()
```

and this is its result:

[image]

Comment: Can you add the desired detail to the figure for clarity (manually, using some drawing program)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to pass the x-coordinates in your plot commands. When you do `plt.plot(YA)`, you are not passing the x-values and they will be taken as 0, 1, 2, 3....

Also, you need to subtract 1 from the x-coordinates to align them on the continuous line. So, do the following changes marked by a comment

```
XA = np.array([6,7,8]) # <--- Convert to array for vectorised subtraction
YA = np.sqrt(XA)
plt.plot(XA-1, YA,'g',marker = '>') # <--- Use XA-1

XB = np.arange(2,5)
YB = np.sqrt(XB)
plt.plot(XB-1, YB,'m',marker = '<') # <--- Use XB-1
```

[image]